# How do I make a file download link with node.js and html?

Tags: html, node.js, http

my current code, which is just a basic node.js server and html  tag, and this does download the file. But if I open the file in notepad, I can see that it actually just downloaded the html code for my site, and named it whatever the intended file was

Here is the HTML download code:

```
<a download href="./examplefile.txt" target="_blank">example</a>
```

and here is the node.js server code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const port = 25565


const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
    fs.readFile("index.html", function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.writeHead(404, { "Content-type": "text/html" })
            res.write('<h1>file not found - 404<h1>')
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            res.write(data)
            console.log('activity has happened')
        }
        res.end()
    }) 
})

server.listen(port, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('something happend bad', error);
    } else {
        console.log('server working on port ' + port)
    }
})
```

Comment: You should read about Content-Disposition header.
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). Use the `fs` module to read the file and pipe it to the `response` object.

Comment: You are linking to a specific file `/examplefile.txt` but you seem to want to return `index.html`. ?